# Android SQLite syntax error SQLiteException (code 1)

Tags: android, android-sqlite

The error I'm getting is `SQLiteException: near ",": syntax error (code 1)`, and I cant figure where my mistake is. 
I´ve read some other questions with the same error and the answer they give is that it's a simple syntax error with a missing comma. However I've checked again and that doesn't seem to be my problem. I've included the code below.

```
public static final String prospectos="RegProspectos.db";
public static final int dbversion = 1;
public static final String tabla_prospectos="prospectos";
public static final String cm_NomProspec="NomProspec";
public static final String cm_ApProspec="ApProspec";
public static final String cm_AmProspec="AmProspec";
public static final String cm_RfcProspec="RfcProspec";
public static final String cm_TelCasa="TelCasa";
public static final String cm_TelOficina="TelOficina";

public adminProspec(Context context)
{super(context,prospectos, null, dbversion);}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    final String crea_tabla=
            "CREATE TABLE "+tabla_prospectos+"("
                    +cm_NomProspec+     " TEXT,"
                    +cm_ApProspec+      " TEXT,"
                    +cm_AmProspec+      " TEXT,"
                    +cm_RfcProspec +    " TEXT,"
                    +cm_TelCasa+        " TEXT,"
                    +cm_TelOficina+     " TEXT,"
                    +cm_UsrActReg+      " TEXT "+")";
    db.execSQL(crea_tabla); }
```

Here is my logcat output:

```
 06-30 11:15:18.083: E/SQLiteDatabase(1867): Error inserting = escobedo=escobedo gurrola=gurrola cesar=cesar Guec=Guec
06-30 11:15:18.083: E/SQLiteDatabase(1867): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near ",": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: INSERT INTO prospectos(,escobedo,gurrola,cesar,Guec) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)
06-30 11:15:18.083: E/SQLiteDatabase(1867):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
06-30 11:15:18.083: E/SQLiteDatabase(1867):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:889)
```

Comment: Show us your Insert into please

Comment: `INSERT INTO prospectos(,escobedo,gurrola,cesar,Guec) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)` You forgot to add the first field name. Here: `(,escobedo`. No, wait. **You completely  messed the insert**: you are inserting the **VALUES** where the **FIELD LIST** has to (optionally) go. The **VALUES** are those funny **?** you have in the insert. And must be passed using a String array.

Comment: database.insert("prospectos",null,altaProspecto);
    bd.close();
    Toast.makeText(this, "Se Cargaron los Datos del Prospecto,",+ Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); here is the sql command or do you want the entire method?

Comment: The problem is with the INSERT code, not with the CREATE TABLE.

Comment: The problem is in content values creation probably, in `altoProspecto`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 06-30 11:15:18.083: E/SQLiteDatabase(1867): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near ",": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: INSERT INTO prospectos(,escobedo,gurrola,cesar,Guec) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)

This error is about an `Insert` that you do somewhere... You put a `comma` inside an `Insert` so your `Insert` should be like this :

```
INSERT INTO prospectos(escobedo,gurrola,cesar,Guec) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)
```

Other issue that I'm seeing is that in your `Insert` you put 4 fields and on your values you put 5, you have to put the same values as fields you put. (I guess your **`?`** values are something that you don't want to show to us, if it's not, you can't pass a `?` to an `Insert`).

See [**SQLite - INSERT Query**](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sqlite/sqlite_insert_query.htm) to know more about `INSERT INTO`.

Answer (score 2):

thank you so much like you said the error where in the insert method,
the problem i think, was that I were trying to insert values instead of fields correct me if I'm wrong, that's simple but i don't know how to explain it...

```
...sNomProspec.getText().toString();
...sApProspec.getText().toString();
...sAmProspec.getText().toString()


     altaProspecto.put(NomProspec, NomProspec);
             altaProspecto.put(ApProspec, ApProspec);
             altaProspecto.put(AmProspec, AmProspec);


     altaProspecto.put("NomProspec", sNomProspec.getText().toString());
             altaProspecto.put("ApProspec", sApProspec.getText().toString());
             altaProspecto.put("AmProspec", sAmProspec.getText().toString());
```

I just added the quotes and changed I corrected and now it works thanks a lot =D

Answer (score 0):

You should use ContentValues to insert your data:

Example:

```
ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
contentValues.put(cm_NomProspec, "nomProstect value");
contentValues.put(cm_ApProspec, "Prostect value");
contentValues.put(cm_RfcProspec, "pfProstect value");
database.insert(tabla_prospectos, null, contentValues);

bd.close(); 
Toast.makeText(this, "Se Cargaron los Datos del Prospecto,",+ Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```